# Getting post data from private page

Tags: query

I'd like to get post data from a private page to show on the rest of the site. The code looks like this:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'page_id=1457' );
while($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();
    setup_postdata( $the_query );
    // do something;
endwhile;
```

But I don't get the data.

Is it because I'm calling the data from a public site that is hidden on a private site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setup_postdata` takes a post object of type `\WP_Post`, but you're passing it a `WP_Query` instead

e.g.

```
global $post;
setup_postdata( $post );
```

Thankfully the solution is trivial, when you call `the_post`, it sets up the current post data for you, so removing that line is all you need to do.

The second issue is that `WP_Query` will filter out private posts if you're not logged in, so setting the post status to private is necessary.

An important thing you're missing though is the clean up call. You need to call `wp_reset_postdata()` when you're done so that code that runs after your loop has the current post and not the last post in your query.

Here's what that query might look like:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'id' => '1457'
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'private'
) );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        // do something;
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

There's a faster way though, you already know the post ID, so we can do this:

```
$p = get_post( 1457 );
if ( null !== $p ) {
    setup_postdata( $p );
    // do things
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a query for this - in fact, that's part of the problem (WordPress will automatically "filter" out private pages for non-logged-in users).

Just get the post and do with it as you wish:

```
if ( $my_page = get_post( 1457 ) ) {
     setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] = $my_page );
     // Whatever you need to do
     wp_reset_postdata();
}
```