# How to add content to a post tied to an Archive template specifically for a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm on wordpress 5.9+ and creating CPT's has become relatively easy. But having a landing page for a CPT is new grounds for me.

- I have successfully created a custom post type called Career Finders
- I have created an archive template for this CPT, named `archive-career-finders.php`
- I can see that template being used from the browser when I go to my local URL `my-site.com/career-finders`

But how do we create either a page or post from WP-admin, that connects to this archive template, and "is" this landing page for the CPT?

I want editors to be able to add content to this landing page through wp-admin.  This is where I am stuck...

**My initial thought:**
On this new archive template, do I use the WP-Query loop to get that "1" page or post that represents the content needed to be displayed here, and also have that page set to Private? Is that the way to go?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question properly, you are looking for templates.  Copy your `single.php` or `page.php` from your theme and then rename it to `single-career-finders.php`.

This is the same thing you should have done for your archive page as well...  Take the `archive.php` file from your theme, copy it and rename to `archive-career-finders.php`.  It will have the appropriate query within it to pull your custom posts but you can alter the content as well.  You don't have to add a separate `WP_Query` here.

Now edit this file and you'll have a custom presentation for your data separate from normal pages, posts, or other CPTs.

This page has a great explanation of how templates work within WordPress:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking, I'm taking the following approach

- Under my CPT area in wp-admin/, create a public post that represents the content for my CPT landing page. This post is naturally located at `my-site.com/career-finders/landing-content`
- From my child theme area, set code in place to hide this post from Archives pages, Search results, RSS feed, and Blog Roles. [This given article](https://nestify.io/blog/hide-posts-or-pages-in-wordpress/) inspired me on the process.
- Within my `archive-career-finders.php` template, call the data from my `/landing-content` page with the help of `setup_postdata($p);`, inspired by [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/243278/98671)
- Now when a user goes to `my-site.com/career-finders` they will see landing page content for my CPT.

This seems to me as the easiest way to allow an wp-admin editor to add content to a post, that is tied to a custom Archive template, for a custom post type.

Comment: why not just create a shortcode to output a WP_QUERY and put that at the bottom (or top) of the post?  OR create a function that will output the query ONLY if you're on the landing page?

Comment: Thanks @pressword.  These are defintly good suggestions. But the goal in end is to (1) have a content editor be able to edit the landing page from Gutenberg, and (2) have that page URL be represented as the landing location for that specific CPT `my-site.com/career-finders/`.